# not receiving the desired output for my binary search tree code in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I got this code by converting a java code into c++ but its not giving me the desired outputs. In the In-order traversal there are missing values, the value of the root node(5) is missing in all the traversals and the Pre-order traversal output is completely missing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree {
private:
    int nodeCount = 0;

    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;

        Node(Node* left, Node* right, T elem) : data(elem), left(left), right(right) {}
    };

    Node* root = nullptr;

public:
    bool isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    int size() {
        return nodeCount;
    }

    bool add(T elem) {
        if (contains(elem)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            root = add(root, elem);
            nodeCount++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    Node* add(Node* node, T elem) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            node = new Node(nullptr, nullptr, elem);
        } else {
            if (elem < node->data) {
                node->left = add(node->left, elem);
            } else {
                node->right = add(node->right, elem);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    bool remove(T elem) {
        if (contains(elem)) {
            root = remove(root, elem);
            nodeCount--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    Node* remove(Node* node, T elem) {
        if (node == nullptr) return nullptr;

        int cmp = elem - node->data;

        if (cmp < 0) {
            node->left = remove(node->left, elem);
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            node->right = remove(node->right, elem);
        } else {
            if (node->left == nullptr) {
                return node->right;
            } else if (node->right == nullptr) {
                return node->left;
            } else {
                Node* tmp = findMin(node->right);
                node->data = tmp->data;
                node->right = remove(node->right, tmp->data);
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    Node* findMin(Node* node) {
        while (node->left != nullptr) node = node->left;
        return node;
    }

    Node* findMax(Node* node) {
        while (node->right != nullptr) node = node->right;
        return node;
    }

    bool contains(T elem) {
        return contains(root, elem);
    }

    bool contains(Node* node, T elem) {
        if (node == nullptr) return false;

        int cmp = elem - node->data;

        if (cmp < 0) {
            return contains(node->left, elem);
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            return contains(node->right, elem);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    int height() {
        return height(root);
    }

    int height(Node* node) {
        if (node == nullptr) return 0;
        return std::max(height(node->left), height(node->right)) + 1;
    }

    enum class TreeTraversalOrder { PRE_ORDER, IN_ORDER, POST_ORDER, LEVEL_ORDER };

    class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T> {
    private:
        std::stack<Node*> stack;
        Node* current;
        const BinarySearchTree<T>* tree;

    public:
        Iterator(const BinarySearchTree<T>* t, TreeTraversalOrder order)
            : tree(t), current(nullptr) {
            if (t->root != nullptr) {
                if (order == TreeTraversalOrder::PRE_ORDER) {
                    stack.push(t->root);
                } else if (order == TreeTraversalOrder::IN_ORDER) {
                    Node* trav = t->root;
                    while (trav != nullptr) {
                        stack.push(trav);
                        trav = trav->left;
                    }
                } else if (order == TreeTraversalOrder::POST_ORDER) {
                    std::stack<Node*> stack1;
                    stack1.push(t->root);
                    while (!stack1.empty()) {
                        Node* node = stack1.top();
                        stack1.pop();
                        if (node != nullptr) {
                            stack.push(node);
                            if (node->left != nullptr) stack1.push(node->left);
                            if (node->right != nullptr) stack1.push(node->right);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (order == TreeTraversalOrder::LEVEL_ORDER) {
                    std::queue<Node*> queue;
                    queue.push(t->root);
                    while (!queue.empty()) {
                        Node* node = queue.front();
                        queue.pop();
                        if (node != nullptr) {
                            stack.push(node);
                            if (node->left != nullptr) queue.push(node->left);
                            if (node->right != nullptr) queue.push(node->right);
                        }
                    }
                }
                current = stack.top();
                stack.pop();
            }
        }

        Iterator& operator++() {
            if (stack.empty()) {
                current = nullptr;
            } else {
                current = stack.top();
                stack.pop();
            }
            return *this;
        }

        Iterator operator++(int) {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

        bool operator==(const Iterator& other) const {
            return current == other.current;
        }

        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const {
            return !(*this == other);
        }

        T operator*() {
            return current->data;
        }
    };

    Iterator begin(TreeTraversalOrder order) const {
        return Iterator(this, order);
    }

    Iterator end() const {
        return Iterator(this, TreeTraversalOrder::PRE_ORDER);
    }
};

int main() {
    BinarySearchTree<int> tree;

    tree.add(5);
    tree.add(3);
    tree.add(7);
    tree.add(2);
    tree.add(4);
    tree.add(6);
    tree.add(8);

    // Traverse the tree in different orders
    std::cout << "In-Order Traversal: ";
    for (auto it = tree.begin(BinarySearchTree<int>::TreeTraversalOrder::IN_ORDER); it != tree.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Pre-Order Traversal: ";
    for (auto it = tree.begin(BinarySearchTree<int>::TreeTraversalOrder::PRE_ORDER); it != tree.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Post-Order Traversal: ";
    for (auto it = tree.begin(BinarySearchTree<int>::TreeTraversalOrder::POST_ORDER); it != tree.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Level-Order Traversal: ";
    for (auto it = tree.begin(BinarySearchTree<int>::TreeTraversalOrder::LEVEL_ORDER); it != tree.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
In-Order Traversal: 2 3
Pre-Order Traversal:
Post-Order Traversal: 2 4 3 6 8 7
Level-Order Traversal: 8 6 4 2 7 3

I'm not too profiecient in c++ and only have an academic level understanding so I don't exactly know what to look for... I have tried searching about the end() function in the Iterator class and I think I should change 'this' to 'nullptr' in its return statement but doing so gives me no output at all as it justs stops at 'In-Order traversal:  ' and the program ends after a few seconds. I have tried changing the != operator function but it only resulted in errors. I have tried asking chatGpt but it only gives the above mentioned solutions.

Comment: We can't debug your program for you. Refer to [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Also it seems you're trying different random things to solve the problem. Instead refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: *I got this code by converting a java code into c++* -- That's your first mistake, and that is trying to "convert" Java code to C++.  The way you properly convert Java to C++ is 1) Know *both* languages,  2) Figure out what the Java code is doing, 3) Throw away the Java code, and implement the same thing in C++, but using C++ idioms and best practices.  Doing line-by-line translations from Java (or any other language) to C++ without proper C++ knowledge will wind up in tears.

Comment: *I have tried asking chatGpt but it only gives the above mentioned solutions.* -- You cannot learn C++ by using chatGPT.

Comment: I'm not sure how you think the iterator code is supposed to work. Look at the in-order path. In the constructor it pushes the left the branch on to a stack and then nothing ever does anything with the right branch so there is no way it could possibly work but even beyond that this is not what is typically meant by an "iterator". You should not be basically copying the entire traversal into the iterator.

Comment: I would suggest not trying to write an iterator as a beginner, which is an advanced topic anyway. the binary tree construction code you have posted looks basically correct  ... try to write three functions that do the three kinds of traversals; rather than an iterator class.

Comment: Binary search tree is already implemented in STL: For simple use cases you can use `std::set`. If this is a practice on implementing data structures, it's too soon for you to try. There are loads of things to learn before getting involved with raw pointers.

Comment: I already did an implementation of the BST with a simpler code for traversal but wanted to try this new approach of doing so. But I guess it turned out to be too complex for me.

Comment: Off the top, `remove` leaks memory, since it doesn't `delete` any node.

Comment: Pre-order traversal doesn't visit any nodes because you treat `Iterator(this, TreeTraversalOrder::PRE_ORDER)` as the end iterator: `begin()` returns the same iterator as `end()`, indicating empty range.

Comment: Similarly, `IN_ORDER` traversal stops after traversing the left sub-tree. At that point, `current == root` and the iterator becomes equal to the end iterator. You probably want to represent end iterator in some way that is distinct from "iterator pointing to root node"; e.g. as an `Iterator` instance having `current == nullptr`.

Comment: Your `contains()` method assumes that the data type is numerical: `int cmp = elem - node->data;`  Templates allow for a multitude of data types.  You should either call `operator<` or call a provide comparison (ordering) function.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, that was very helpful. Now I know where and what the mistakes are exactly.